# Is it possible to use digitalocean droplet as a server and with aws s3 as hosting image?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, server, digital-ocean, droplet

I am looking to use `digitalocean` droplet as a server but I need to host an image , especially , a large image and I have chosen `aws s3`.
Is it possible to use `digitalocean` droplet as a server and with the `aws s3` as a hosting image ?

Comment: Yes, that will work perfectly fine.  Might  (or might not) be some CORS issues you need to resolve, but nothing difficult to handle.

Comment: Yes, your server doesn't have to be in AWS in order to use S3. DigitalOcean also has their Spaces service which is similar to S3 if you wanted to keep everything in the same data center.

Comment: @MarkB thanks for the answer but if i use s3 is it gonna effect with image loading performance?

Comment: Thanks for the answer @user2263572

Comment: @Syafil not if you allow S3 to serve the image directly to the client. It will affect performance if you still serve the images through your server by downloading it from S3 and then sending it to the client.

Comment: Thanks @MarkB i understand now